# Switch Arabic Numbers To English In String

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the time in my device, It's returning the time in GMT, and i'm converting it to Local .

The time i'm getting is for example : 23:00, When switching to Locale it returns in Arabic numbers, When i take the time from JSON, it doesn't switch it to Arabic .

Code :

```
    private String GMTToLocal(String InputText){
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat
            ("yyyy:M:dd kk:mm", Locale.US);
    inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
    // Adjust locale and zone appropriately
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(InputText);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputFormat.format(date);
}
```

I tried the following, but didn't work :

```
String Tes2 = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,Arabic_Letters_String);
```

The problem in short, i need the time in English letters/numbers, not in Arabic, this only happens when i get the time from my device, but if i get it from JSON, it takes it as English and return it as English, but from the device, it takes it as Arabic and return it as 0 value ( because Simpledateformat takes English only i guess ) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SimpleDataFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) has a constructor accepting a `Locale`. By default the device locale is used, thus giving you arabic numbers.

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm", Locale.US);
```